# How to securely share (export) files of a VirtualBox virtual machine with (to) the host?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, security, virtual-machine

I'm running Debian 9 with KDE and have a virtual machine in VirtualBox. I can pass files into it without having to use the somewhat insecure "shared folders" or "shared clipboard" or "drag and drop" enabled by creating an .iso file with the data and adding that under its "Storage" options.

But how can I securely export files from the virtual machine to my host system?

Comment: Why is using the shared folder insecure? The shared folder is only visible by the guest and the host.. right? Also you can always "email" it out from the VM after encrypting it inside the VM. What kind of security are you thinking of?

Comment: @Darius Well I'd just like to isolate virtual machines (particularly those running proprietary operating systems which I don't trust) as good as possible. Here is [a relevant question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/102989/139250).    I'd like to use a method that works without Internet connection. Or can you email it out to the host machine while offline? I'm asking because there might be an easy to use method that I don't know of and as I'd like to have VMs properly isolated - not because I'd like to do anything really "requiring" such precautions per se.

Comment: I'm with @Darius, nothing inherently insecure in the shared folders. Normally the VM cannot write outside the shared directory (if it can you can report the vulnerability to the VirtualBox dev team). If you have an SMTP server on your Debian, then the VM can send mail to it even if your Debian isn't connected to a network.